# How to support Comodo SSL cert in loopj on Android?

Tags: android, ssl, loopj

I'm running a site using HTTPS with an SSL cert from [Comodo](https://www.comodo.com/). [Qualys](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) gives an A+ score for the site and the same URL works without errors in Chrome on Android. When I try to connect to the site from an Android app using loopj, I get an `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` exception. Do I have to manually provide certificate info?

I see this behavior with the default [AsyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) example:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("https://myapp.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // called before request is started
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
        // called when request is retried
    }
});
```

Exception:

```
04-20 21:59:57.092: W/System.err(8824): javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLNullSession.getPeerCertificates(SSLNullSession.java:104)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:214)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:167)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeSB(DefaultRequestDirector.java:831)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:697)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:575)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:491)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:147)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:178)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:109)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-20 21:59:57.102: W/System.err(8824):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to loopj, you can just create an AsyncTask that will perform
the task on the program. Almost the same way as loop is doing it. I used the class below to perform HTTP/S request and it does the job.

```
class GetHTTPSTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
  {
    private String mUrl;

    public GetHTTPSTask(String url)
    {
      this.mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
      try
      {
        URL urlConnection = new URL(mUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection
          .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

        return Boolean.TRUE;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
      if ( result != null)
      {
        // Connection was successful
        // Do something here
      }
      super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
  }
```

And to use it:

```
new GetHTTPSTask("https://www.google.com/").execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the server cannot rely on SNI if you're using Apache libraries.

If you have control of the server, you can configure it have a unique IP. Or, fix on the client:

From the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html):

> Fortunately, HttpsURLConnection supports SNI since Android 2.3.
>   Unfortunately, Apache HTTP Client does not, which is one of the many
>   reasons we discourage its use. One workaround if you need to support
>   Android 2.2 (and older) or Apache HTTP Client is to set up an
>   alternative virtual host on a unique port so that it's unambiguous
>   which server certificate to return.